# I am trying to configure my application in IIS7. but after configuring I am not able to browse the website

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created an application with .net framework version 4.0. I am trying to configure this application in IIS. But after the configuration, when I am try to browse the particular website I am getting the following error.

> Server Error in '/' Application. Configuration Error Description: An
>   error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required
>   to service this request. Please review the specific error details
>   below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file:
>   Failed to start monitoring changes to 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2013\Projects\Project2' because access is denied.
>
> Source Error:
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File: C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Project2\web.config    Line: 0
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237

Comment: Is that the correct path?

Is Project2 the solution path, or the WebRoot path?

Comment: i guess you configure invalid source path.

Comment: Will you tell in brief what you did?